# Django ifchanged template tag rendering when it should not

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I am trying to render out a table there are a bunch of djangos `{% ifchanged %}` conditions that should only render out the value if changes all of them work as intended except the one where I check for whether or not the `code_product_type_id` has changed but it renders it out anyway. for eg. the first 3 iterations, the `code_product_type_id = 100` but it still renders as if it changed. it is unqiue, its the key of the dictionary and does not change unless you move to the next key in the dict at which point it should render out. Any suggestions as to why this might be happening?

1. I've tried using `product.product_type` in the `ifchanged` tag and still gives the same result.
2. I've tried creating extra context with a `with` clause just after the outer most for loop, still the same result.

All the bold text in the image below is what is rendered out and the integers are the `code_product_type_id` to illustrate the the value is not changing

[image: what is rendered]

#### Template

```
{% for code_product_type_id, product_types in report_rows.items %}

                    {% for code_product_id, products in product_types.items %}
                        {% for code_company_id, product in products.items %}

                            {# FIXME: I am not rendering out correctly and I don't know why #}
                            {% ifchanged code_product_type_id %}
                                <tr class="font-weight-bold">
                                    <td colspan="3">{{ product.product_type }} - {{ code_product_type_id }}</td>
                                </tr>
                            {% endifchanged %}

                            <tr>
                                {% ifchanged code_product_id %}
                                    <td>{{ product.product_name }}</td>
                                {% else %}
                                    <td></td>
                                {% endifchanged %}

                                {% ifchanged code_company_id %}
                                    <td>{{ product.company_name }}</td>
                                {% else %}
                                    <td></td>
                                {% endifchanged %}

                                <td>{{ product.date_valid_to|date:"d.m.y" }}</td>
                            </tr>
                        {% endfor %}
                    {% endfor %}
                {% endfor %}
```